# Trying to make a program that you push a button, choose a file, and the program then prints a certain value from that file

Tags: python-3.x

I'm very new to coding and I tried a bunch of different things but none of them are working for me.

Here is my code. With this code everything is working correctly so far, but i'm unsure of how to implement the read function into my code. My main problem is that in everyone's read examples they use the exact filename, whereas I need to use raw input.

Edit: I was able to solve this on my own, by using open(filename, "r") it lets you pick which file to read. Instead of having "6543.txt" which would only open that specific file.

```
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename

root = Tk()
root.title("Amazon Error Handler")
root.geometry("300x150")

frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack()
bottomframe = Frame(root)
bottomframe.pack( side = BOTTOM )
def getfile():
    filename = askopenfilename()
    print(filename)
    getfile = open(filename,"r")
    print(getfile.read(1))
    print(getfile.read())
button = Button(frame, text="Choose File", fg="black", command=getfile)
button.pack( side = BOTTOM)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: @JonathanPorter Sorry for not giving enough information, I updated the question to show my exact problem.

Comment: @JonathanPorter it is a text file, and they all get saved as different names. Like 6543, 6544, 6545, etc. I've noticed that in everyone else's read examples they used the file name like this '6543' but in my case I need it to be a user input and there are no examples of this for me to work off of.

Comment: @JonathanPorter i now have it to where when i push the "choose file" button i made it does print out the file, but it only prints the file "6604570358017437.txt" so i've made progress, but i still need it to print whatever file i choose.

Comment: If you want a user to type in the name why don't you use the function `input()`? e.g. `filename = input()`. Then you can append the file type on like this: `getfile = open("{}.txt".format(filename), "r")`

Comment: @JonathanPorter I was able to figure it out on my own finally. It was actually very simple. Instead of using "name of file" I just put filename without quotes and now my program works as it should. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code I used to solve my own problem. This program is just a button that reads a chosen file and prints it's contents.

```
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename

root = Tk()
root.title("Amazon Error Handler")
root.geometry("300x150")

frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack()
bottomframe = Frame(root)
bottomframe.pack( side = BOTTOM )
def getfile():
    filename = askopenfilename()
    print(filename)
    getfile = open(filename,"r")
    print(getfile.read(1))
    print(getfile.read())
button = Button(frame, text="Choose File", fg="black", command=getfile)
button.pack( side = BOTTOM)

root.mainloop()
```